# This java date arithmetic code gives different answers on different platforms

Tags: java

Given this code and my assumption that the third Friday of November 2013 is the 15th:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import static java.lang.String.format;

public class Wat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        final GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(utc);

        //This is inlined code that sets up a date
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        //This is my third-friday-in-month code
        cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 3);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);

        final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        formatter.setTimeZone(utc);
        final String thirdFridayOfNovember2013 = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(
            format("Third Friday of November 2013 is %s? %s!", 
                thirdFridayOfNovember2013, 
                thirdFridayOfNovember2013.equals("15-11-2013")));
    }
}
```

Here is a copy from my terminal of running it on Linux:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-47-142-178:~$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-47-142-178 3.2.0-61-virtual #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:54:33 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@ip-10-47-142-178:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
ubuntu@ip-10-47-142-178:~$ java -classpath . Wat
Third Friday of November 2013 is 15-11-2013? true!
ubuntu@ip-10-47-142-178:~$
```

Here is a copy from my terminal of running on os x:

```
gasp $ uname -a
Darwin Mikes-MacBook-Pro-2.local 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Wed Apr  2 23:52:02 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.92.1~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
:gasp $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
:gasp $ java -classpath . Wat
Third Friday of November 2013 is 22-11-2013? false!
:gasp $
```

My colleague next me ran it on a Linux dist with Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13) and he also got the 22nd.

I am completely at a loss as to why this is happening - can somebody please shed some light.

Comment: You should use new Java8 Time API, if you allowed to do so.

Comment: yes, that would be nice, but not possible in current environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue could be locale specific. Check Calendar documentation

> First Week
>
> Calendar defines a locale-specific seven day week using two
>   parameters: the first day of the week *and the minimal days in first
>   week (from 1 to 7).*

I suggest you print `calendar.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` in both platforms and compare

Comment: Oh my god.  Really!  Thanks for pointing this out to me.  The linux box has minimal days in first week as 1, my os x box had it at 4.  I changed my week-calcing code to set this value to 1 on the calendar instance before doing the arithmetic and now its consistent.  Thanks!

Comment: From the `GregorianCalendar` javadoc: "Week 1 of a month (the days with `WEEK_OF_MONTH = 1`) is the earliest set of at least `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` contiguous days in that month, ending on the day before `getFirstDayOfWeek()`.  Unlike week 1 of a year, week 1 of a month may be shorter than 7 days, need not start on `getFirstDayOfWeek()`, and will not include days of the previous month.  Days of a month before week 1 have a `WEEK_OF_MONTH` of 0.