# Why number of days between 2 dates are not coming up correctly?

Tags: java, linux, date

I am currently trying to get the number of days between 2 dates.

`Date1 : 21-JAN-15`

`Date2 : 23-JUL-15`

In my local eclipse tomcat server (in India), I am getting the number of days as: `183` with the following code:

```
Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();

Date date1 = new Date("21-JAN-15");
Date date2 = new Date("23-JUL-15");

cal1.setTime(date1);
cal2.setTime(date2);

System.out.println("Days= "+daysBetween(cal1.getTime(),cal2.getTime()));

public int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2){
         return (int)( (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
 }
```

When I copy the same java file to a linux server and run the file there using `javac` and `java` commands, I get the difference as: 182, which is one day less.

I have confirmed the default timezone of the linux server is EDT using the command: `date +%z`

I am very confused here. I do not have JODA library in my application and I can't use it. What changes do I need to make to get a uniform result both in my local environment and the linux server? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Most likely your time zones are still different. Perhaps Java gets the time zone from somewhere different than `date` does. Try running `System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());`.

If I had to guess, I'd say daylight savings is the cause of the problem. In the US, March has 1 fewer hour because of this shift -- it's 30.96 days long by your metric, which will round down to 30.

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914695/this-java-date-arithmetic-code-gives-different-answers-on-different-platforms

Comment: @BrianMalehorn : Checked the time zone . In my local it prints : India Standard Time . In Linux server , it prints : Eastern Standard Time .

Comment: @singhakash : The thread that you have shown does not help me . the mimimaldaysinfirstweek is set as 1 both in my local and the linux server .

Comment: [Why you shouldn't calculate date/time yourself (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)

Comment: @MadProgrammern : The video was a great eye opener . However, I have got to do it as it is required for me . I am trying to find a way of solving this problem from my problem set context , though i understand it is very difficult to solve in the general context .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `TimeUnit`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date1 = new Date("21-JAN-15");
    Date date2 = new Date("23-JUL-15");

    long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diffInMillies));
}
```

output:

> 182

Comment: Output On My Machine is 183. TimeZone is "India Standard Time"

Comment: Timezone Found out by Using System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());

Comment: this seems to corroborate @BrianMalehorn hypothesis